# How can I tell what row of a tableview I'm looking at in objective c? Is that a way to get the number of the row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, row, tableview

Question says it all.  I'm just having trouble figuring this out.

What i'm trying to do is this:  I have an array of letters from a to e.  I set the sections of the table to 2, so that the rows are as follows: a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e.  I want to have the row and section # display next to the letter in the table.  I can figure out the row using indexPath, but i can't figure out how to compute the section number

Comment: I will work on it :)  but here's the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but if you know the indexPath then you also know the section (see docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175))

```
int sectionNum = indexPath.section
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the indexpath section

```
int section = indexPath.section;
```